# How can I reference a user globally in Django for all Exceptions?

Tags: python, django, exception, django-rest-framework

I have two questions that correlate.

1) Does django-rest-framework have a way to reference a user globally?

2) Does django / python allow me to change the generic exception class to include this user ID as meta every time it throws?

I know I can create custom exception classes and raise them in code, but what about an exception I don’t correctly handle? For example, let’s say a divide by zero exception is thrown but I didn’t correctly handle it, right now my logs just say “Divide by zero exception”.
Is there a way to update this globally so if a user is logged in it says “Divide by zero exception for user_id {id}“?

```
class SomeExternalApiHelper:
    @staticmethod
    def do_api_call():
        url = 'https://example.com'
        # do api request
        try:
            home_value = 100 / 0
        except Exception as e:
            # Exception occurs here, I want to be able to reference user_id, without having
            # to pass the user_object all the way down into this call
            raise Exception("Something went wrong for user ID {0}".format(user_id))


class AddNewHouse(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # I can call request.user here and access the user object
        SomeExternalApiHelper.do_api_call()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) that catches all exceptions, you can then log the exception along with the user

```
def exception_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        try:
            response = get_response(request)
        except Exception as e:
            # You now have the exception and request.user and can log how you like
            raise
    return response

return middleware
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you